# My queue does not update as I am enqueuing and dequeueing

Tags: c++, node.js, linked-list, queue

I am learning queue's and I am struggling this implementation with a linked list. Below in my code I am trying to implement en-queue and de-queue methods, but as I implement these methods my link list fails to update. I feel it might have something to do with my pointers. Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// A linked list node 
class Node 
{ 
  public:
    int data; 
    Node *next;
    Node()
    {
      data = 0;
      next = nullptr;
    }
    Node(int data)
    {
      this->data = data;
      next = nullptr;
    }
}; 

class List 
{ 
  public:
    struct Node* head;
    struct Node* tail;
    List()
    {
      head = tail = nullptr;
    }
}; 

void ListPrint(List *list)
{
  Node *tempNode = list->head;
  while(tempNode != nullptr){
    cout<<tempNode->data<<",";
    tempNode = tempNode->next;

  }
}


void ListAppend(List *list, Node *newNode)
{
   if(list->head == nullptr)
   {
      list->head = newNode;
      list->tail = newNode;
   }
   else{
      list->tail->next = newNode;
      list->tail = newNode;
   }
}

void ListRemoveAfter(List *list, Node *curNode) {
   // Special case, remove head
   Node *sucNode;
   if (curNode == nullptr && list->head != nullptr) {
      sucNode = list->head->next;
      //delete(list->head);
      list->head = sucNode;

      if (sucNode == nullptr) { // Removed last item
         list->tail = nullptr;
      }
   }
   else if (curNode->next != nullptr) {
      sucNode = curNode->next->next;
      //delete(curNode->next);
      curNode->next = sucNode;

      if (sucNode == nullptr) { // Removed tail
         list->tail = curNode;
      }
   }
}
void enqueue(List *queue, Node *newItem)
{
  ListAppend(queue, newItem);
  ListPrint(queue);
}

Node dequeue(List *queue)
{
  Node poppedItem = queue->head-> data;
  ListRemoveAfter(queue, nullptr);
  return poppedItem;
}

void isEmpty(List *queue)
{

}
int main() {
  List *myQueue= new List;
  int data;
  char input;

  do
  {
    cout<<"\nCurrent Queue: ";
    ListPrint(myQueue);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"\nEnter Queue operation: ";
    cout<<"Enqueue(e), dequeue(d), quit(q): ";
    cin>>input;
    switch(input)
    {
      case 'e':
        cout<<"enter data to enqueue: ";
        cin>>data;
        enqueue(myQueue, new Node(data));
        break;

      case 'd':
        if(!isEmpty(myQueue)){
          Node* poppedItem = dequeue(myQueue);
          cout<<"Dequeued: "<<poppedItem->data;
          delete(poppedItem);
        }
        else
          cout<<"Queue Empty";
       break;

    }

  }while(input != 'q');
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?  It doesn't compile.

Comment: This code does not compile, also dequeu returns data instead of pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself ***is working***, albeit, not compiling in its current state (added an edit to make it compile). When it compiles, I get the correct output when enqueuing items into it.

However, the code is far from being *good*:

1. First and foremost, ***it isn't a C++ code***, but C with some C++ notations - there is no usage of classes, which creates these `ListPrint` and `ListAppend` which are 100% **C** functions.
2. It doesn't follow the API of Queue (FIFO, meaning there is **no remove after**!).
3. It is prone to memory leaks by using raw pointers (which is a bad practice after C++11).

Look at the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Queue
{
public:
    T pop()
    {
        if (size > 0)
        {
            T ret_val = head->data;
            if (size == 1)
            {
                head = nullptr;
                tail = nullptr;
            }
            else
            {
                head = head->next;
            }

            --size;

            return ret_val; // here the previous head has no more references, thus deleted.
        }
        else
        {
            // some error handling.
        }
    }

    void push(T value)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> node = std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>(new Node<T>(value));

        if (size == 0)
        {
            head = node;
            tail = node;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = node;
            tail = node;
        }

        ++size;
    }

    void print() const
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Empty Queue" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> node = head;

            std::cout << "Queue of size " << size << ": ";

            while (node != nullptr)
            {
                std::cout << node->data << ",";
                node = node->next;
            }

            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    bool isEmpty() const { return size == 0; }

private:
    template <typename S>
    struct Node
    {
        S data;
        std::shared_ptr<Node<S>> next;

        Node(S data) :
            data(data),
            next(nullptr)
        {
        }
    };

    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> head = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> tail = nullptr;
    uint64_t size = 0;
};



int main()
{
    Queue<int> q;

    q.print();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        q.push(i);
        q.print();
    }

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Popped: " << q.pop() << std::endl;
        q.print();
    }
}
```

Its output is:

```
Empty Queue
Queue of size 1: 0,
Queue of size 2: 0,1,
Queue of size 3: 0,1,2,
Queue of size 4: 0,1,2,3,
Queue of size 5: 0,1,2,3,4,
Queue of size 6: 0,1,2,3,4,5,
Queue of size 7: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,
Queue of size 8: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
Queue of size 9: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
Queue of size 10: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
Queue of size 9: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
Queue of size 8: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
Queue of size 7: 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
Queue of size 6: 4,5,6,7,8,9,
Queue of size 5: 5,6,7,8,9,
Queue of size 4: 6,7,8,9,
Queue of size 3: 7,8,9,
Queue of size 2: 8,9,
Queue of size 1: 9,
Empty Queue
```

As expected.

This code is using classes (something that was completely missing from your code!), simplified pop algorithm, smart pointers to handle the memory management, and is capable to hold any type of data, not only integers!